# Regading about JSON data parsing in Android

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I am using openweather API for calling current location.In JSON parsing, I saw                    `"dt": 1457852143` (UTC/unix) `http://openweathermap.org/weather-data` which means last updated.So in my app, I stored that value in String variable  `String last_update=total.getString("dt")` where total holding the full JSON data.I ran my app and got the output as 1457852143 on screen.Although I wanted it to show in local time but I am unable to convert.
I am using Android Studio 1.5.Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please be a little more clear on what you have tried already that did not work. You may go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn about how to ask a question in this community.

Comment: 1457852143 convert it to UTC unix. it is a miliseconds in time. That is TimeStamping same for FireBase.

Comment: Aizen, yes I do know it is UTC but I can't able to format it to local time zone.Could you help me with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the following before to do this. This is using the Date class but I've heard it's better to use the Calendar class. This should get you in the right direction though.

```
    public static String convertUTCtoLocalTime(String p_city, String p_UTCDateTime) throws Exception{

String lv_dateFormateInLocalTimeZone="";//Will hold the final converted date
Datelv_localDate = null;
Stringlv_localTimeZone ="";
SimpleDateFormat lv_formatter;
SimpleDateFormat lv_parser;

//Temp for testing(mapping of cities and timezones will eventually be in a properties file
if(p_city.equals("LON")){
lv_localTimeZone="Europe/London";
}else if(p_city.equals("NBI")){
lv_localTimeZone="EAT";
}else if(p_city.equals("BRS")){
lv_localTimeZone="Europe/Brussels";
}else if(p_city.equals("MNT")){
lv_localTimeZone="America/Montreal";
}else if(p_city.equals("LAS")){
lv_localTimeZone="PST";}

//create a new Date object using the UTC timezone
lv_parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
lv_parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
lv_localDate = lv_parser.parse(p_UTCDateTime);

//Set output format - // prints "2007/10/25  18:35:07 EDT(-0400)"
lv_formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z'('Z')'");
System.out.println("convertUTCtoLocalTime "+p_city+": "+ "The Date in the UTC time zone(UTC) " + lv_formatter.format(lv_localDate));

//Convert the UTC date to Local timezone
lv_formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(lv_localTimeZone));
lv_dateFormateInLocalTimeZone = lv_formatter.format(lv_localDate);
System.out.println("convertUTCtoLocalTime: "+p_city+": "+"The Date in the LocalTime Zone time zone " + lv_formatter.format(lv_localDate));

return lv_dateFormateInLocalTimeZone;
}
```